# Dismiss soft keyboard

Tags: c#, keyboard, xamarin.forms

I have a page where the idea is to use it with external keyboards. When the page loads, I set the focus on an `Entry` control and I want to hide the soft keyboard.

This is the class where I want to do that:

```
internal class RedactContent : ContentPage
{
    StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();
    Entry entry;

    internal RedactContent()
    {

        entry = new Entry();
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {                
                entry,
                //more code
            }
        };
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        entry.Focus();
        // Hide Keyboard
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create CustomEntry with CloseKeyboard method. For this you need to write custom renderers for each platform. See http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

On Android your CustomEntry class could look like this:

```net
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
public class CustomEntryRenderer :  EntryRenderer
{
    public CustomEntryRenderer()
    {
        HideKeyboard();
    }

    void HideKeyboard()
    {
        this.Control.InputType = 0;
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = this.Control.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
        inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! how can I replace "this.Control.InputType" in a class in Android project? Tried "Form.Context" but it don't have Control defined

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by replace this.Control.InputType but look at example renderer for entry here https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/ExtendedEntry/ExtendedEntryRenderer.cs and https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/ExtendedEntry.cs

Answer (score 0):

```
* First create a derivated class from Entry

    public class KBLessEntry : Entry
    { 
    public KBLessEntry() : base()
    {
    }
    }

* Then create a custom platform EntryRender

    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using MobileClients.Droid.Core;
    using Android.Views.InputMethods;
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(KBLessEntry), typeof(KBLessEntryRender))]
namespace MobileClients.Droid.Core
{
    public class KBLessEntryRender : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            Control.InputType = 0;
            try
            {             
                // Hide keyboard
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = this.Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
                if (inputMethodManager != null)
                {
                    inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception Ex)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

And in XAML

```
<local:KBLessEntry x:Name="TxtCode" FontSize="18" Placeholder="Código producto" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></local:KBLessEntry>
```

local: must be defined has a namespace in your xaml xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MobileClients.Droid.Core;assembly=MobileClients.Droid" where the derivated Entry class (in this case KBLessEntry) resides

And thats it

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = ActivityCreateAccount.this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: place this code in the place of comment //Hide KeyBoard

Comment: Add some explanation

Comment: there is a comment //Hide Keyboard  in your code, just place this code there

Comment: This is for Xamarin Android, not Xamarin.Forms.